# ASP. NET ASHX 302 issue with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET app using .NET Framework 4.7.2. It had a modal pop-up to the user to enter some notes and then save. The user sometimes uses the button which shows the pop-up and enters notes which are rejected on the postback due to the authentication having expired. I'd like to do a quick check on authentication when the window pops up, so I thought I'd try a .ashx page
I got this code from chatGPT:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'yourHandler.ashx',
type: 'GET', // or 'POST'
success: function(response) {
    // Do something with the response
    console.log(response);
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    // Handle any errors
    console.error(error);
}
```

});

This gives me a 302 back to my default.aspx . Is there a better way to do this? Can I fix the 302 with code or configuration? I was wondering if I needed to register the ashx somewhere.

TIA, my ASP.NET programming skills are limited :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are on a web page, and you don't want session to expire?

Just add a simple web method to that existing page, and fire a JavaScript timer to call some "dummy" web method.

I mean, either you let the session expire, or you don't. So, you can keep the page alive as long as you want. Or, when the user does some action that requires server-side code, then they will receive a logon prompt again. So, to avoid this issue, then we keep the page alive and don't let session expire.

So, assuming you have jQuery, then in your markup, you can say trigger a simple tiny request to the web page. As long as they are on that web page, then their session will never time out.

So, say this JavaScript/jQuery - you can place right at end of form, and thus this:

```
    <script>

        $(window).on('load', function () {
            // web page fully loaded
            // start a little javascript function to run every 1 minute

            setTimeout(MyTickTok(), 60000)

        })

        function MyTickTok() {

            // any web method call re-sets session time out.

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Test/TableMunch.aspx/TickTock") %>',
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    setTimeout(MyTickTok, 60000) // run again in 60 seconds
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    var r = request.responseText
                    var errorMessage = r.Message
                    console.log(errorMessage)
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
```

And code behind for that web page, simply add a web method such as:

(Imports System.Web.Services)

```
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function TickTock() As String

    Return "hello"

End Function
```

So, now the session will not time out, since we "touch" the web page every 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had something like that doing a save, I was trying to move away from compromising security. Also this pop-up is in master and on multiple pages, hence my idea for a little ajax on the problem. I'll save this for 'plan B' :-)

Comment: What does that <WebMethod> do?  Does it enable AJAX? I don't want a timer, but I could just do a simple AJAX call to a method in the PageBase before I show the pop-up :-)

Comment: Webmethods simple define that routine in the code behind as a web based end point. At that point, then a rest call, a soap call, or a jQuery.ajax call all work, and you can use xml, or json data format. So, it s a web api "end point".  Keep in mind if that is a secured web page, and session goes out, then the ajax call will also fail.  So, it guess the question then is what do you want to do if the web call fails due to the user's session having been lost? So, not aware of any security's issue here. If user requires a logon to use that page, then the web end point is secured.

Comment: That;s exactly what I want to do, check the authentication and the sesion and make them login again if they've expired. The button must check that and then, if ok, show the pop-up.

Comment: Have the simple web method return the logged on name - if it returns  blank, then assume the user is logged off, and re-direct to the logon page. As noted, you can create a separate web service page (asmx), or you can tag the code as a static web method of the current page - and get/return the logged on user. Do keep in mind that such web methods of a given page have to be static to the page class, since no instance of the web page is created when you call such webmethods. So, have your JavaScript click code that pops hte dialog FIRST call/check if user is logged on.......

Comment: Thanks for your help @albert-d-kallal you have more than solved my problem and I have accepted your answer  :-)